# Div from js not expanding with content

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all I've been browsing for a while trying to avoid opening yet another "div not expanding" question, but I haven't found a solution yet.

I'm building a web reporting tool with SCOM data I get via powershell scripting. We don't have access to SCOM reporting tools, that's why I have to build a website *by hand*.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>SCOM Reporting</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href=".\style\style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1 id="header">SCOM WEB REPORTING TOOL</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="navbar">
    <a href="#HOME" id="HOME" onClick="changeGuay(this.id)">Home</a>
    <a href="#PROD" id="PROD" onClick="changeGuay(this.id);">PROD</a>
    <a href="#ABN" id="ABN" onClick="changeGuay(this.id)">ABN</a>
    <a href="#EDEN" id="EDEN" onClick="changeGuay(this.id)">EDEN</a>
  </div>

  <div class="div_report" id="divReport">
  </div>

  <script src=".\js\scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My css

```
/* Style the body */
body, html {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  min-height:100%;
}

/* Header/logo Title */
.header {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: DarkSeaGreen;
  color: white;
}

/* Increase the font size of the heading */
.header h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: DimGrey;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

/* Main column */
.main {
  padding: 20px;
}

.div_report {
  width: auto;
  height: 500px;
  border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And my js

```
function changeGuay(id){
  changeHeader(id);
  changeContent(id);
}


function changeHeader(id) {
  if (id === "HOME") {
    document.getElementById("header").innerText = "SCOM WEB REPORTING TOOL";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("header").innerText = id + " REPORTING";
  }
}

function changeContent(id){
  if (id === "HOME"){
    document.getElementById("divReport").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="about:blank"></object>';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("divReport").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="'+id+'.html"></object>';
  }
}
```

The div content changes to whatever I want as I desire but the content it shows doesn't expand at all, it remains as a small square. I'd like it to fill the rest of the empty space of the page, with the vertical scroll since the data I'm pulling from SCOM is long.

Live example here : https://codepen.io/bala421/pen/wvMqKwy

Comment: Add a rule for the object elements to the style sheet, like `.div_report object {width:100%; height:500px;}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the div, it is that you are using an `<object> </object>`. Select the `object` and apply the styles to it. I used this

```
object{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for basic grid layout i suggest bootstrap.
but anyway,

```
.div_report {
  width: 100%;
}
```